# Generate different PDFs with mailmerge depending on cell value - Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mailmerge

I'm running an Apps Script in Google Sheets to Mail merge and generate a PDF file which is then store in Drive.

I have the following variable which stores the Google Doc that serves as template for the new PDF being generated.

```
var GDOC_TEMPLATE_ID = '1olnBowCh-1apK3jWN-Lr2Ty3UT1NK_dmoJOVBjnzgO8'
```

I would like to have a function that modifies the value of this variable so that it can point to a different file.

What I have been trying to do is the following script but haven't accomplished at all:

- If "selected row's column N cell is empty, use this file, if cell is not empty, change to a different file ID.

Note: My mail merge script runs by selecting row and gets all the place holders from the selected row, so when one of those fields is empty, I'm trying to point to a different template that suits better.

[This is the script being used, it is public in GitHub and has instructions for each part of the process](https://gist.github.com/lcenchew/5bb4f7f23a159d66dc9a14f38d222fcf)

Thanks

Comment: It would be a lot easier to assist you if you would provide us with a [mcve]

Comment: @Cooper, thanks, updated

Comment: It does not include [mcve] posted in the question

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and my answer was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You are using a script of https://gist.github.com/lcenchew/5bb4f7f23a159d66dc9a14f38d222fcf.
- In your script, first, it selects a cell. And, run the script. By this, the row of the selected cell is used as the value.
- Under this condition, when the value of column "N" is empty, you want to use the file ID of `1olnBowCh-1apK3jWN-Lr2Ty3UT1NK_dmoJOVBjnzgO8` as `GDOC_TEMPLATE_ID`. When the value of column "N" is not empty, you want to use the other file ID as `GDOC_TEMPLATE_ID`.

In this case, how about the following modification? Please modify `getSheetData()` as follows.

#### From:

```js
function getSheetData() {
  
  copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById(GDOC_TEMPLATE_ID).makeCopy()
  var copyId = copyFile.getId()
  copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId)
  copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection()
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var numberOfColumns = activeSheet.getLastColumn()
  activeRowIndex = activeSheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex()
  var activeRowRange = activeSheet.getRange(activeRowIndex, 1, 1, numberOfColumns)
  activeRowValues = activeRowRange.getDisplayValues()
  headerRow = activeSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numberOfColumns).getValues()
}
```

#### To:

Please replace `### other ID ###` with your file ID.

```js
function getSheetData() {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var numberOfColumns = activeSheet.getLastColumn()
  activeRowIndex = activeSheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex()
  var activeRowRange = activeSheet.getRange(activeRowIndex, 1, 1, numberOfColumns)
  activeRowValues = activeRowRange.getDisplayValues()
  headerRow = activeSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numberOfColumns).getValues()

  var templateIds = ['1olnBowCh-1apK3jWN-Lr2Ty3UT1NK_dmoJOVBjnzgO8', '### other ID ###'];
  GDOC_TEMPLATE_ID = templateIds[activeRowValues[0][13] ? 1 : 0];

  copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById(GDOC_TEMPLATE_ID).makeCopy()
  var copyId = copyFile.getId()
  copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId)
  copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection()
}
```

- By this modification, when the value of column "N" of the row of the selected cell is empty, `1olnBowCh-1apK3jWN-Lr2Ty3UT1NK_dmoJOVBjnzgO8` is used as `GDOC_TEMPLATE_ID`. When the value of column "N" is not empty, the other file ID `### other ID ###` is used as `GDOC_TEMPLATE_ID`.

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly as expected. Is it also possible to consider a 3rd or 4th scenario for different templateIds and not just 2? Thanks

Comment: @Darkoder Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `Is it also possible to consider a 3rd or 4th scenario for different templateIds and not just 2?`, I think that the answer to your new question is yes. But, in your current situation, a situation whether the value of column "N" is empty. is used. If you want to use the template ID by the value of column "N", I think that an object can be also used.